# how can i set a marker tool as default selected in markerjs library

Tags: javascript, image, image-annotations

i am using the library markerjs (https://markerjs.com/docs/events/) for doing annotation over an image and i am not sure how to make the freehand drawing tool as default selected because right now the select mode tool comes as autoselected does anyone have any idea about it?

I have gone through the documentation and i found the below given constructor but i am not sure how to use it tried it like markerArea.setActiveMarkerButton("FreeHandMarker") but this doesn't work
setActiveMarkerButton
setActiveMarkerButton(typeName: string): void
Selects toolbar button for a specified marker type.

since
2.17.0

Parameters
typeName: string
Marker type name

Returns void
i found the above constructor in the document below
https://markerjs.com/reference/classes/toolbar#setactivemarkerbutton

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: MY CODE

function showMarkerArea(target) {
        const markerArea = new markerjs2.MarkerArea(ssImage);
        markerArea.addEventListener("render", (event) => {
          target.src = event.dataUrl;
          chrome.storage.local.set({ base64AnnotatedImg: event.dataUrl });
          processSaveChanges();
        });
        markerArea.show();
        }
      const ssImage = document.getElementById("screenshot-image");
      ssImage.src = url;
      showMarkerArea(ssImage);